# Factoring Trick - Adding Up Coefficients

Tags: polynomials, education, factoring, rational-functions

My professor told me this for factoring polynomials:

> Add up the coefficients and if they equal 0 then the polynomial has root of 1.
>
> Add up, but switch the signs of the coefficients with odd number powers. If sum = 0 then there is a root of -1.

I just want to make sure when he means this is the $c$ term added up in this neat little trick.

I didn't think so, but I want to make sure.

Do you guys know?

Comment: if p(x) is a polynomial, p(n) = $\sum {a_i x^i}$, then p(1) = $\sum {a_i }$ , the sum of the coefficients, as desired.  p(-1) is handled the same way.  Not sure what you meant by "the c term".  If you meant the constant term then, yes: it must be included.

Comment: @lulu Okay then, what if we change the signs do we have to change the sign of the constant term as well?

Comment: In the case of p(-1)?  No...the rule you gave said to change the sign for the odd numbered powers.  the constant term is attached to $x^0$, an even numbered power.

Comment: Okay thanks that's what I was thinking. You should post an answer since you kind of anwered it perfectly in the comments. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 'trick' your professor taught you is actually what is called the remainder theorem. Basically what it says is that if you have a polynomial: $p(x)$ and you calculate the value of $p(d)$ then $p(d)$ is the remainder when $p(x)$ is divided by $(x-d)$. For example $p(x) = x^2 -2x+1$. Let $d=1$ and we get:$$p(d) = p(1) = 1^2-2(1)+1 = 1-2+1 = 0$$ Thus $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x-1)$ so it has root $d = 1$. Notice that in the last step ($1-2+1$) all we are doing is adding the coefficients and because the sum is equal to $0$ it is indeed divisible by $1$. The same applies for $d=-1$. When we put $-1$ in the polynomial we are switching the signs of all the coefficients with odd powers just like your professor taught you to.

Comment: So for the **c** we don't have to change the sign when doing for odd?

Comment: @Asker123 I did not understand that part of the question and I apologize, what is c? What do you mean by it?

Comment: **c** as in the constant, It's okay now, but thanks for providing a new way of looking into it.

Comment: @Asker123 OH never mind the answer to your question is no do not change it for c

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is my solution in answer form.

if p(x) = $\sum {a_i}{x^i}$ is a polynomial then p(1) = $\sum {a_i}$ is the sum of the coefficients.  similarly, p(-1) is the sum of the even numbered coefficients minus the sum of the odd numbered coefficients.

To be clear:  the constant term is the degree 0 term, an even numbered coefficient, so its sign does not change

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "this is the $c$ term added up", but here are some examples:

$P(x) =  3 x^4 - 2 x^3 + x^2 - 2$: $3 - 2 + 1 + 0 - 2 = 0$ so $1$ is a root.
$3 + 2 + 1 - 0 - 2 = 4$ so $-1$ is not a root.

Comment: So for the **c** we don't have to change the sign when doing for odd?

Comment: The constant term is the coefficient of $x^0$, which is thus one of the even number powers, not odd.